# Ruby on Rails - form_for collection_select options not visable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using a collection_select in a form_for however the options are not displaying in the browser (empty select box) but are present in the debugger view. (this happens in both chrome and IE10).

View:

```
<%= form_for(@lot) do |f| %>
<%= f.label :client_id, "Client" %>
<%= f.select :client_id, collection_select(:lot, :client_id, Client.all, :id, :org, :include_blank => "Please select") %>
```

Rendered page source:

```
<label for="lot_client_id">Client</label>
<select id="lot_client_id" name="lot[client_id]"></select>
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">Client 1</option>
<option value="2">client 2</option>
```

Controller:

```
def new
  @lot = Lot.new(:client_id => 1)
end
```

Any insight would be much appreciated thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

collection_select is also a [formHelper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select) of sorts which returns both a select and options elements, try:

`<%= f.collection_select(:lot, :client_id, Client.all, :id, :org, :include_blank => "Please select") %>`

instead

Comment: Thanks, this partially resolved it. as the form was for @lot I needed to also drop the :lot making it     <%= f.collection_select(:client_id, Client.all, :id, :org) %>:

Answer (score 1):

you can try this as eg.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all,:id,:name, :required=>true) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering collection_select helper inside the select helper, which is wrong. You have to do it like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:client_id, Client.all, :id, :org, :include_blank => "Please select") %>
```